# How to update single column in laravel

Tags: updates, laravel-5.3

I am new in Laravel and I'm trying to create an application. I have created a form and I use a controller to store this form into my database.The form has a drop-down field named "Status".

The "Status" is like "Categories" so I need to change this without changing anything else. I am trying to write the code but I am doing something wrong. You can see my code below:

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $servicedevice = DeviceService::findOrFail($id);

        return view('device_service.show', compact('servicedevice', $servicedevice));
    }       

public function devicestatus(Request $request)
        {
          $devstat = DeviceService::FindOrFail($servicedevice->id);
          $devstat->status_id = $request->device_id;
          $devstat->save();

          return back();
        }
```

View:

```
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'DeviceServiceController@devicestatus']) !!}
            {!! Form::select('status_id', $statuslist, null, [
                'class' => 'js-example-basic-single',
                'style' => 'width:50%'
                ]) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('id', $servicedevice->id) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('ok', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-flat btn-warning']) !!}
            {!! Form::close(); !!}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/devicestatus', 'DeviceServiceController@devicestatus');
```

When I try to change The "Status", returns the following error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

in RouteCollection.php line 218
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 780
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message and stack trace tells you exactly what happened:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
...
RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD'))
```

You are submitting a form (which is `POST` method by default) but you only define the route as `Route::get`.

You need to change that to `Route::any` or define a second route `Route::post` to the same URL but with a different method call.

Comment: I feel stupid for not paying more attention. That worked, thank you very much.

Comment: @EmirianJaku That's ok, just remember to read through the stack trace from the exception. Often that will tell you what happened, or at least point you in the right direction. For example, maybe you wouldn't know what the solution is here but at least you would know that the problem is with the route and not with updating the column.